# How to prevent stretching/scaling of a DirectX C++ program

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2017, directx, screen-resolution

I have built a very straightforward C++ program using DirectX9 that presents images and text on the screen. I have compiled it for 1024 x 768 and I want to make sure it is compatible on any screen resolution. When trying to run my executable on a 1920 x 1080 monitor, the program automatically stretches horizontally (as this monitor is a widescreen) and distorts the images and text. I have been told there is a flag I can change when initalizing DirectX, which will prevent any stretching and make sure the program opens with vertical black bars on either side to preserve all my desired formatting. Does anybody know how to do this? Here is an excerpt from my code that initalizes DirectX. PS: I am setting the refresh rate to 0, so that my program will run on any monitor's native refresh rate.
Thank you!

```
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name: InitD3D()
Desc: Creates the D3D object using Direct3D
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
HRESULT InitD3D(HWND hWnd) {
   if (NULL == (pD3D = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION)))
      return E_FAIL;

   D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;
   ZeroMemory(&d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp));
   d3dpp.Windowed = FALSE;
   d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
   d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8;
   d3dpp.BackBufferCount = 1;
   d3dpp.BackBufferWidth = 1024;
   d3dpp.BackBufferHeight = 768;
   d3dpp.FullScreen_RefreshRateInHz = 0;

   if (FAILED(pD3D->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, hWnd,
      D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING,
      &d3dpp, &pd3dDevice)))
      return E_FAIL;

   return S_OK;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: Why would you be learning directx9 at this point? if you aim to work building games you shouldn't really care much about learning graphics APIs unless you're interested in the heavily optimization of the GPU, maybe learn Unity or Unreal Engine for building games. However it is a good idea to know and understand how things work behind the scenes, if so, I would recommend that you would go for Directx 11.2 as Directx9 is legacy.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Viewport (D3DEVIEWPORT9) could help you, you can set the position of your image on the window through this structure. Then there is an API to obtain the resolution of the monitor. the resolution of the monitor minus the resolution of the image, and finally divide by 2, the result is the position of the upper left corner of your image on the screen. The following code is for your reference.

```
int nScreenWidth, nScreenHeight;
nScreenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
nScreenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
D3DEVIEWPORT9 vp = { (nScreenWidth - 1024) / 2,(nScreenHeight - 768) / 2,1024,768,0,1 };
pd3dDevice->SetViewport(&vp);
```